# Play Framework [2.3.0 - Java] Access to play.Configuration.root() during tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to access configuration values during unit tests with Play Framework (2.3.0, Java). Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to provide a FakeApplication (of course...)
For example, by the wrapping class WithApplication :

```
WithApplication app = new WithApplication();
app.startPlay();
Configuration.root().getString(key);
app.stopPlay();
```

Comment: I got around this problem by `extend`ing my testClass to be a child of `WithApplication`, and `startPlay()` in `setUp()` and `stopPlay()` in `tearDown()`. Thanks!